# Laravel Validation Call to a member function fails() on array

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm making a form that can only use certain values. But whenever type a correct answer its returns and array anyone knows if I can do it this way or if I have to change too many things

```php
$validator = $request->validate([
    'wattage' => ['required', new CertainValue()]
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    Log::error('validatiefout:', $request->all());
    
    return redirect('/test');
}
```

CertainValue RULE (use App\Rules\CertainValue;)

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CertainValue implements Rule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if ($value === "5") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

Code for error in blade.php (with the fix I don't get the errors back in a ul)

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Add the declaration of `CertainValue` class in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control what happens when the validation fails you cannot use `$request->validate()`, because it throws an exception when the validation fails and returns automatically, if the validation passes `$request->validate()` will return the validated data from the request and not a `Validator` instance so you will have to manually create the `Validator` if you want to redirect yourself.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators):

> If you do not want to use the validate method on the request, you may
>   create a validator instance manually using the Validator facade. The
>   make method on the facade generates a new validator instance:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    ['wattage' => ['required', new CertainValue]]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    Log::error('validatiefout:', $request->all());

    return redirect('/test')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i was searching for a long time. I did find the docs just didn't know how to put the "new CertainValue" into it

Comment: Know I do not get an error back. Do you also know how to fix that (added the code above)

Comment: I updated my answer, you have to add `->withErrors($validator)` to flash the errors to the session and `withInput()` if you want the input values that were submitted with the request.